# magento category category collection show include_in_menu

Tags: magento-1.9, category

i have code that show all category with details but i want to show "include_in_menu" yes or no in output array also .

i am using below code :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("name")->addAttributeToFilter("is_active", "1")->setLoadProductCount(true)->setProductStoreId($store);
```

Array output that i get :

```
"categories": [
    {
        "category_id": "11",
        "parent_id": "3",
        "name": "adbcd",
        "is_active": "1",
        "level": "2",
        "products_count": 0,
        "display_mode": "PRODUCTS",
        "thumbnail_url": null,
        "children": 10
    },
    {
        "category_id": "12",
        "parent_id": "85",
        "name": "abc",
        "is_active": "1",
        "level": "3",
        "products_count": 42,
        "display_mode": "PRODUCTS",
        "thumbnail_url": null,
        "children": 0
    },
```

i want to add is **include_in_menu** to array how can it be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chnage your code as below:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter("is_active", "1")->setLoadProductCount(true)->setProductStoreId($store);

foreach($collection as $child){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($child->getData());
}
```

Output as below:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 3
    [entity_type_id] => 3
    [attribute_set_id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 2
    [created_at] => 2016-04-25 09:32:12
    [updated_at] => 2016-04-25 09:32:12
    [path] => 1/2/3
    [position] => 1
    [level] => 2
    [children_count] => 0
    [is_active] => 1
    [name] => test
    [meta_title] => 
    [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
    [custom_design] => 
    [page_layout] => 
    [url_key] => test
    [url_path] => test.html
    [description] => 
    [meta_keywords] => 
    [meta_description] => 
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [available_sort_by] => 
    [include_in_menu] => 1
    [landing_page] => 
    [is_anchor] => 0
    [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0
    [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
    [filter_price_range] => 
    [product_count] => 1
)
```

Comment: hey this code just show active menu i want it in array

Comment: I have updated code as well as output.